# Apache Spark - ReducedWindowedDStream has not been initialized

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am restarting a Spark streaming job that is checkpointed in HDFS. I am purposely killing the job after 5 minutes and restarting it to test the recovery. I receive this error once  **ssc.start()** is invoked.

```
INFO WriteAheadLogManager : Recovered 1 write ahead log files from hdfs://...receivedBlockMetadata
INFO WriteAheadLogManager : Reading from the logs:
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ReducedWindowedDStream@65600fb3 has not been initialized
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.isTimeValid(DStream.scala:321)
```

I am starting the job using: **StreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkpointDir,...**

The job has three windowed operations that are sliding windows of 5 minutes, 1 hour, and 1 day, but the job was stopped after 5 minutes.  In order for the recovery from the checkpoint to work, does the maximum windowed duration need to pass for all the windowed ops to initialize?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and I deleted the checkpoint path on HDFS to avoid the exception